# Why can't I add variables with 1x1 tibbles to a tibble with tibble::add_row?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

This is a simple example of what I am trying to do. Why can't I add a row with each variable a 1x1 tibble?

```
d <- tibble(x = 2, y = 3)
x1 <- tibble(1)
y1 <- tibble(7)

d2 <- d %>%
  tibble::add_row(
    x = x1,
    y = y1
  )
```

I know the following works but it is not tidy and it just seems like there should be a better way.

```
d <- tibble(x = 2, y = 3)
x1 <- tibble(1)
y1 <- tibble(7)

d2 <- d %>%
  tibble::add_row(
    x = as.numeric(x1),
    y = as.numeric(y1)
  )
```

Thanks in advance awesome R people (:

Comment: You're trying to insert a whole dataset into a single cell in your first attempt. You need to select the single column out of the dataset to add as rows - `add_row(d, x = x1[[1]], y = y1[[1]])` . Running `as.numeric(x1)` just converts `x1` to a `vector` in a round-about way, which will also work. You could also go full `dplyr` and do `add_row(d, x = pull(x1,1), y = pull(y1,1))` if you wanted to avoid using the `[[` brackets.

Comment: Is there a reason x1 and y1 have to be tibbles? Your first attempt works fine if they are just numbers.

Comment: They are tibbles because I was selecting them from a tibble e.g. if my tibble is called `tibble_obj`, then I was getting the value using `tibble_obj[1, 3]` but now I understand that if I use `tibble_obj[[1, 3]]` that gives me just the value instead of another tibble and everything works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading comment to an answer:

You're trying to insert a whole dataset ('tibble' in this instance) into a single cell in your first attempt. You need to select the single column out of the dataset to add as rows.

```
add_row(d, x = x1[[1]], y = y1[[1]])
```

Running `as.numeric(x1)` also converts `x1` to a vector in a round-about way, which as you've found, will also work.

You could also go full *dplyr* and do:

```
add_row(d, x = pull(x1,1), y = pull(y1,1))
```

...if you wanted to avoid using the `[[` brackets.